# how to implement a linked blocking queue in LIFO mode

Tags: java, queue, fifo, lifo

the title already says it all, in my code I have an object that implements a Linked Blocking Queue and offers methods of inserting and obtaining an element in the queue, I would like the insertion / extraction from the queue to take place in a LIFO way and not in a FIFO way , is there any way to do it?

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class Usr {
    private BlockingQueue<String> requestsQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();

    public Usr() {

    }

    public void insertRequest(String username) {

        try {
            this.requestsQueue.put(username);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getRequest() {
        try {
            return this.requestsQueue.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace your `LinkedBlockingQueue` with **`LinkedBlockingDeque`** and use **`takeLast()`** instead of `take()`.

Deque is a collection that supports element insertion and removal at both ends. See details here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html

Cheers!